# Draw Circles Inside Polygon in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, polygon, geometry

I'm using react.js and I currently know how to put a hole in a polygon via the following:

```
drawShape(google){
    var entireMap = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85.1054596961173, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85.1054596961173, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85.1054596961173, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85.1054596961173, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85.1054596961173, 0)];

 var innerCoords = [
    {lat: 28.745, lng: -70.579},
    {lat: 29.570, lng: -67.514},
    {lat: 27.339, lng: -66.668}
  ];

    const poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [entireMap, innerCoords],
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#000000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    poly.setMap(google.map);
    }
```

Right now, I have a list of properties that contain lng and lat. Instead of having polygon as holes I want to have circles as holes, using the lng and lat.

So far, I see that the documentation allows you to create circles separately:

```
var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    });
```

However, I would like the circles to be "holes" within the `entireMap` polygon. Is it possible to combine the `entireMap` shape and circle shape or would I need to create a function that creates circles from the polygon shape?

Comment: related question: [Change map opacity outside circle of Google Maps JavaScript API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736418/change-map-opacity-outside-circle-of-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)

Comment: related question: [Google Map API v3 shade everything EXCEPT for polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130323/google-map-api-v3-shade-everything-except-for-polygon)

Comment: related question: [Drawing multiple holes into a polygon - google maps api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919276/drawing-multiple-holes-into-a-polygon-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0):

The following is the component I'm using to draw a polygon in map with a cut out circle in it. It's written with React in mind but the solution can be extracted for other libs/frameworks

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useGoogleMap } from '@react-google-maps/api'

import { Map as MapConsts } from 'assets/consts'

const getCirclePath = (
  center: google.maps.LatLng | google.maps.LatLngLiteral,
  radius: number,
  numParts = 512
) => {
  const path = []
  for (let i = 0; i < numParts; i += 1) {
    path.push(
      google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(
        center,
        radius,
        (i * 360) / numParts
      )
    )
  }
  return path
}

type Props = {
  center: google.maps.LatLng | google.maps.LatLngLiteral,
  radius: number
}

function SearchRadius({ center, radius }) {
  const map = useGoogleMap()

  useEffect(() => {
    // calculate inner circle path
    const innerCircle = getCirclePath(center, radius)
    const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: [MapConsts.OUTER_BOUNDS, innerCircle],
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#000000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map,
    })

    return () => {
      // remove polygon from map
      polygon.setMap(null)
    }
  }, [center, radius])

  return null
}

export default SearchRadius
```

This solution requires the geometry library, to add that you can check [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15226237/5749192)